# Can one set Windows SDK compatibility target?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, compatibility

While developing a Windows application that uses the Windows SDK which you want to be able to run from Windows 7 to Windows 10; is there a way to ensure you use only features supported by the oldest OS?

I got VS2017 installed and it comes with v10 of the SDK.

I'm looking for a way for the IDE to flag that a feature isn't available.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the [`WINVER`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070411-00/?p=27283), `_WIN32_WINNT` and [`NTDDI_VERSION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx) defines that controls which features are "visible" are poorly designed because they apply to constants and functions.

This means you must set these defines to the oldest version you support and manually define constants and structs for new functions you call with `GetProcAddress` (if any).

If you set them to the highest version you risk increasing the size of some structs and this will break the `struct.cbStruct = sizeof(struct)` pattern on older versions of Windows. (Windows 2000+ SDKs broke the [`OPENFILENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646840(v=vs.85).aspx) and `NOTIFYICONDATA` structs when the application runs on 9x/NT4 etc).

Ideally the Windows SDK should let you specify both and the headers would look like this:

```
#if TARGET_WINMAXVER >= 0x601
typedef enum { FF_BAR = 0x01 } FOOFLAGS;
#endif
#if TARGET_WINMINVER >= 0x601
BOOL WINAPI Foo(FOOFLAGS Flags);
#endif
```

but sadly Microsoft never adopted this. This would expose the flags but hide the function so you always stay ABI compatible.

Comment: Would using an older SDK version be an alternative?

Comment: There is no need, just set _WIN32_WINNT and NTDDI_VERSION to the Windows 7 values and you should be safe.

Comment: Turns out one only need to set `_WIN32_WINNT` and the `SDKDDKVer.h` will set `WINVER` and `NTDDI_VERSION` for you.

Comment: @thomthom This depends on your SDK version but it has been true for anything >= Vista I'm guessing. Back in the old days you might want to target IE4 on Win95 etc. and then you had to set each define to exactly the version you require.